# Interpretation of range(n) and boolean list, one-to-one map, simpler?

Tags: python, variable-assignment

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#
# Description: bitwise factorization and then trying to find
# an elegant way to print numbers

# Source: http://forums.xkcd.com/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=61300#p2195422
# bug with large numbers such as 99, but main point in simplifying it
#
def primes(n):
    # all even numbers greater than 2 are not prime.
    s = [False]*2 + [True]*2 + [False,True]*((n-4)//2) + [False]*(n%2)
    i = 3;
    while i*i < n:
        # get rid of ** and skip even numbers.
        s[i*i : n : i*2] = [False]*(1+(n-i*i)//(i*2))
        i += 2
        # skip non-primes
        while not s[i]: i += 2
    return s


# TRIAL: can you find a simpler way to print them?
# feeling the overuse of assignments but cannot see a way to get it simpler
#
p = 49
boolPrimes = primes(p)
numbs = range(len(boolPrimes))
mydict = dict(zip(numbs, boolPrimes))

print([numb for numb in numbs if mydict[numb]])
```

**Something I am looking for, can you get `TRIAL` to be of the extreme simplicity below? Any such method?**

```
a=[True, False, True]
b=[1,2,3]
b_a                    # any such simple way to get it evaluated to [1,3]
                       # above a crude way to do it in TRIAL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For python2.7+, you can use [itertools.compress](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress)

```
itertools.compress(b,a)
```

eg

```
>>> from itertools import compress
>>> a=[True, False, True]
>>> b=[1,2,3]
>>> list(compress(b,a))
[1, 3]
```

otherwise you can use a list comprehension

```
>>> [j for i,j in zip(a,b) if i]
[1, 3]
```

If you want to do this on your list of primes, it may be simpler to use enumerate

```
>>> primes = [False, False, True, True, False, True]
>>> list(compress(*zip(*enumerate(primes))))
[2, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) along with a list comprehension to greatly simplify that to this:

```
p = 49
print([num for num, isprime in enumerate(primes(p)) if isprime])
```

Answer (score 0):

Making a dict here is not what you want anyway, because dicts are unordered. Keeping the pairs as pairs actually simplifies the logic, because you can iterate over pairs, give the two elements names, and use those names in the comprehension.

The Pythonic way to 'zip' a list with a parallel list of indices is to use `enumerate`.

Thus:

```
print ([x for (x, y) in enumerate(primes(49)) if y])
```